# Can you use "limits" in geometry proofs?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

Let's say that I wanted to prove power of a point for a tangent and secant. The diagram would look something like this. Let's say that I am allowed to use the power of a point for a a secant and a secant. Would this proof be valid?
[image]

Now, I take the "limit" as $B$ approaches $A$. It would look something like this.

[image]

So, in the final diagram, points $A$ , $B$, are in the same place, let's call this place $P$. Since the power of point for secant-secant remained through through this whole transformation until this very exact point, we still have that $(EB)(EA) = (ED)(EC)$ because even a very small nudge away makes this true, so this is still basically true even though the points are in the same place. However, in this case, $EB$ & $EA$ have become the single segment $PE$. Thus our original equation becomes $(PE)^2 = (ED)(EC)$, thus proving power of a point for a secant and a tangent.

Comment: Power of a point?  Please define!

Comment: It's a theorem from geometry

Comment: It gave me the equation I have in the first picture

Comment: @herbsteinberg Some call [power of a point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) with respect to a circle the difference between the squared distance from the center and the squared radius. However, here he's reffering to the theorem that says that the segments on secant rays from a point outside a circle are inversely proportional.

Comment: Thanks ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Imo it depends on the mathematical framework you use. If you are doing *cartesian* geometry in $\Bbb R^2$, you can of cause use limiting procedures, but have to check things like continuity. If you are doing *axiomatic* geometry in the style of Euclid, you better only use axioms and theorems derived from them. A posteriori it doesn’t matter, since one can show both types of euclidean geometry agree. But as a matter of taste/style I think one should be careful with mixing different frameworks in proofs. It is a great source of intuition though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a little bit of rigor, you can do this of course.

1. You need to define what means $B$ approaches $A$. For example, you can take the angle $\theta=\angle DEB$ and say $\theta\to\theta_{\tau}$, where $\theta_\tau$ is the angle between $CD$ and the tangent from $E$ to the circle (let's call the point $A_\tau=B_\tau=T$).
2. Next, you want to show that indeed $A\to T$, when $\theta\to \theta_\tau$. With a little bit of geometry involved, you can show that $AT(\theta_\tau-\theta)<k\sqrt{\theta_\tau-\theta}$, where $k$ is some constant. Since $AT\to 0$, then $A\to T$.
3. Finally, since the distance is a well-behaving function of two points (triangle inequality), $A\to T$ implies $EA\to ET$.

Repeat the same with $B$ and you are done.

Of course, if you are describing your proof to someone informally, you can just say what you said “as A approaches B, secant becomes tangent and bla-bla”. Meaning, the listener can easily fill in the gaps listed above.

Comment: Thanks, will wait for more answers to come in before accepting +1